# Will the small proportion ruin the ability of chi-square test?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, chi-squared-test, unbalanced-classes

Let me raise an example to be clear: say I have a 2*2 contingency table as follows:

5 10

10000 10000

I assume it satisfies the assumptions of chi-square test. But the proportion ~ 0.05% is very small. Will it cause a problem? E.g. the effect size can be small I suspect.

Comment: What are the assumptions to which you refer and what exactly do you mean by "effective size"?  I suspect your question has been addressed already in many threads on this site: please see https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=chi+square+test+assumption+5.

Comment: The assumption includes independence and min frequency of 5 for each cell. For effect size, a classical one for chi square test is Cramer's V score.

Comment: A minimum frequency of 5 in each cell is not an assumption of the chi-squared test.  A standard rule of thumb is that the p-value is reliable provided the *expected* frequencies in a large proportion of cells are at least 5.  That is something you can find in the link I provided earlier.

Comment: My mistake. But my example still satisfies the expected frequency requirements. Is it appropriate to do a chi square test?

Comment: Look to the duplicates to confirm you are correct in that supposition.  They are clear about this.